# (Recursive) Regular expression for .htaccess file

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, url-rewriting

I'm trying to modify my web page, which I currently use QueryStrings to display pages, and want to change website URLs to "search engine friendly" ones.

I'm a newbie in regular expressions and also in .htaccess file, and I want to change URLs from

```
http://someaddress.bla/index.php?lang=en&rootCategory=$rootCaty&leafCategory=$leafCat
```

to

```
http://someaddress.bla/en/$rootCat/$sub-category/$sub-category2/.../$leafCat
```

Categories are stored recursively on the database so, I have to display each category level in URL. But what I need is only the last category in the url. for instance the category may be a root category like:

```
http://someaddresss.bla/en/Company
```

which is currently displayed from the URL:

```
http://someaddress.bla/?lang=en&RootCategory=Company
```

or it may be a sub-category like:

```
http://someaddress.bla/en/Company/AboutUs
```

which is currently displayed from the URL:

```
http://someaddress.bla/?lang=en&RootCategory=Company&LeafCategory=AboutUs
```

or may be a leaf like:

`http://someaddress.bla/en/Company/AboutUs/Staff/.../Steve` where "Steve" is the leaf in recursion.
This page is currently displayed from the URL:

```
http://someaddress.bla/?lang=en&RootCategory=Company&LeafCategory=Steve
```

I couldn't write the regular expression to handle this situation, any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered mod_rewrite all 404 requests to a single PHP file and do perform your regex within that file?

Comment: I didn't understand what you are really talking about with "mod_rewrite all 404 requests to a single PHP file", but I have several php files, and I can check if the content is missing or not with php. 
I'm planning to change the regular expression to 
"RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ someFile.php?lang=$1&RootCategory=$2 

RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.+)?/([^/]+)/?$ someFile.php?lang=$1&RootCategory=$2&LeafCategory=$4"
where I handle data in someFile.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?lang=$1&RootCategory=$2
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.+)?/([^/]+)/?$ /?lang=$1&RootCategory=$2&LeafCategory=$4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match the last item in the URL by anchoring to `$` (the "end of string" character):

```
([^/]+)$
```

will match and capture the last set of characters in the URL that is not a `/` character.